# Regex replace multiple %20 spaces with only one space

Tags: javascript, regex

How do get all groups of `(%20)` with an regex, and replace with on.

```js
var str= "/geocode/%20%C3xxx%20%20%20%20.json&language="
console.log(str.split(/(%20)+/g).join("%20"))
```

Comment: How about `str.replace(/(%20)+/g, "%20")`?

Comment: I want to determine multiple %20 groups with one

Comment: `"/geocode/%20%20%20%C3xxx%20%20%20%20.json&language=".replace(/(%20)+/g, "%20")` => `/geocode/%20%C3xxx%20.json&language=` - like this?

Comment: The `split` also outputs captured texts. In your code, you need `/(?:%20)+/`. In the `.replace`, you could still use your pattern without issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace multiple occurences with a unique one, I would use this :

```js
var str= "/geocode/%20%C3xxx%20%20%20%20.json&language="
alert(str.replace(/(%20)+/g, "%20"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want just replace / remove them, you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) javascript function.

```js
const url = '/geocode/%20%C3xxx%20%20%20%20.json&language=';

console.log(url.replace(/\%20/g, ''));
```